# BASH scripting: Organizing output of a nested loop into a table

Tags: arrays, bash, printf, echo

I have wasted so much of my time with this, I hope someone can help me. I am editing a script that is used to send values to an executable and then scrubs the output from the executable for tabulation. I have created two arrays that are filled with user inputted ranges, these ranges are then used to create a nested loop that I have put into a function (since I need to create 4 files from the output depending on another value). I admit that my code is abysmal, but it does the primary thing and that is obtaining the data I need and puts into the correct file. All I am trying to do is to get it to actually make a table with row and column labels, I just can't understand why this is so difficult.
This is the problematic area:

```
# Function to loop user inputted ranges in order to generate report data.
function repeat()
{
    printf "%22s" 'density (10^18 m^-3)' 
    for a in "${density_array[@]}"  # for loop to list density values in the range set by the user.
    do
        printf "%13s" "$a"
    done
    echo -e "\n" 'speed (m/s)'
    #printf "%s\n" "${speed_array[@]}"
    for i in "${speed_array[@]}"
    do 
        echo "$i"
        for j in "${density_array[@]}"
        do
            echo $j > SCATINPUT     # generates a temporary file named SCATINPUT, with density value as first line.
            echo $temp >> SCATINPUT # appends a new line with temperature value to SCATINPUT file.
            echo $i >> SCATINPUT    # appends a new line with speed value to SCATINPUT file.
            echo $1 >> SCATINPUT    # appends a new line with rate type from argument to SCATINPUT file.

# pipes contents of SCATINPUT file to executable, extracts  value from STDOUT to RATE variable.
            RATE=`path_of_executable < SCATINPUT | awk '/0\./'` 

            RATEF=$(printf "%.4e" $RATE)    # converts number in RATE variable to scientific notation with 4 digits after decimal and sets RATEF variable.
            echo -ne "\t$RATEF"
            rm -f SCATINPUT # quietly deletes SCATINPUT file.
        done
    done
}
```

I am getting this output in a file:

```
density (10^18 m^-3)   2.0000e+00   4.0000e+00   6.0000e+00

speed (m/s)
8.0000e+06
7.6164e+04  1.4849e+05  2.1936e+059.0000e+06
5.7701e+04  1.1249e+05  1.6619e+051.0000e+07
4.3469e+04  8.4747e+04  1.2520e+051.1000e+07
3.3078e+04  6.4488e+04  9.5269e+041.2000e+07
2.5588e+04  4.9886e+04  7.3697e+04
```

But it should be this:

```
density (10^18 m^-3)   2.0000e+00   4.0000e+00   6.0000e+00

speed (m/s)
8.0000e+06             7.6164e+04   1.4849e+05  2.1936e+05
9.0000e+06             5.7701e+04   1.1249e+05  1.6619e+05
1.0000e+07             4.3469e+04   8.4747e+04  1.2520e+05
1.1000e+07             3.3078e+04   6.4488e+04  9.5269e+04
1.2000e+07             2.5588e+04   4.9886e+04  7.3697e+04
```

Comment: start by replacing `echo "$i"` with `printf "%22s" "$i"`=> this should leave the cursor on the same line as `$i` and lined up under the `2.0000e+00`; after you finish the `j` loop and before getting the next `i` => `printf "\n"` => this should move the cursor to the next line and ready for the next `printf "%22s" "$i"`; that should get you started; if things don't line up quite right then consider replacing the `echo-ne "\tRATEF"` with a `printf "%#s" "$RATEF"` (adjust the number `#` to line up output as desired)

Comment: Just stop using `echo` entirely, use `printf` for everything. It gives you much more control.

Comment: Thank you! You guys are awesome! YES! I ended up using `printf "-22s" "$i"` for the `i` loop. Then I changed the echo in the `echo -ne "\t$RATEF"` in the `j` loop to `printf "%13" "$RATEF"` and added `printf "\n"` between the `done` and `done`

Comment: How do I mark this as answered? I actually feel that it probably was a ridiculous question to ask...

Comment: `printf "\t%s" "$RATEF"` can replace `echo -ne "\t$RATEF"` as well (if you just use `printf`, you can simplify things) You ask @markp to post an answer so you can select it. (give him a bit -- he may have stepped away for dinner, etc..) If no answer by tomorrow you can select, drop another comment and someone can write one up -- but it is fair to give him a chance since he provided the original solution.

Comment: I have been at this for two weeks, `printf` is what I was using at the end, though I did start with `echo` as a proof of concept, but neither were working in the way I wanted them to work.  The main culprit, I think, was the missing `printf "\n"` between the loops.

Comment: @CrazyIvan1978 copied my comment to an answer block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea would be to replace the `echo` commands with comparable `printf` commands with formats that match the formats used to print the first/header line ...

Start by replacing `echo "$i"` with `printf "%22s" "$i"` => this should leave the cursor on the same line as `$i` and lined up under the `2.0000e+00`

After you finish the `j` loop and before getting the next `i` do `printf "\n"` => this should move the cursor to the next line and ready for the next `printf "%22s" "$i"`.

That should get you started.

If things don't line up quite right then consider replacing the `echo -ne "\tRATEF"` with a `printf "%#s" "$RATEF"` (adjust the number # to line up output as desired).